# How to run code automatically when launching a Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Let's say I wanted a greeting every time the Rails console comes up:

```
Scotts-MBP-4:ucode scott$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
Hello there! I'm a custom greeting
2.1.5 :001 >
```

Where would I put the `puts 'Hello there! I\'m a custom greeting'` statement?

Another Stackoverflow answer suggested, and I've read this elsewhere too, that I can put that in an initializer like this:

```
# config/initializers/console_greeting.rb
if defined?(Rails::Console)
  puts 'Hello there! I\'m a custom greeting'
end
```

That doesn't work for me though :(. Even without the `if defined?(Rails::Console)` I still don't get output. Seems like initializers are not run when I enter a console, despite what others suggest.

Comment: I routinely put them exactly where you indicate, without the `if defined?(Rails::Console)`, and have never had an issue... I wonder if there is something else at play, here?

Comment: The "Hello there...." line ***does*** get displayed when I run the server with `rails s`. So the initializer is getting executed. Just not when launching a console. Only when launching the whole server.

Comment: `bwerth@worth:~/rails/my_site$ bundle exec rails c`

`"Devise monkey patch for v 3.4.1. Check before moving on"`

`Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.2)`

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `p ('Devise monkey patch for v 3.4.1. Check before moving on')` is the first line in `config/initializers/devise_minkey_patch.rb`... What other gems are you using? Any logger shenanigains?

Answer (score 6):

The following will work in **Rails 6**:

Just pass a block to `Rails.application.console`, e.g

```rb
    # config/initializers/custom_console_message.rb
    if Rails.env.production?
      Rails.application.console do
        puts "Custom message here"
      end
    end
```

Now when starting the rails production console, the custom message will be printed. This code will not be executed when you start rails server.

Remove the `if Rails.env.production?` if you want this to run in all environments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if there is a file location - kinda like the /tests folder - that guaranteed will not be loaded in a production db? I do note that you have a conditional `Rails.env.production?` but was curious if there was a different way to handle it?

Comment: Not a file location, no. 
I still think this is quite a clean solution - to avoid use in prod you could just switch it to `unless Rails.env.production?` or whatever.

Answer (score 4):

I use ~/.irbrc for similar purposes (I require a gem in each console session). For example, my .irbrc

```
if (defined? Rails)
  # Rails specific
end

# common for all irb sessions
```

You could use your project name to limit executing code to only one project's console:

```
if (defined? Rails) && (defined? YourProject)
  # code goes here
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with Heroku as well?